# How to through sprite body in upper direction

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

How to through sprite body in upper direction?
I want to use box2d for through body.
When it through upper direction it looks like jump sprite body.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to apply a force or an impulse (which is a force applied in a time stamp only). See this link http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumping

Comment: Thanks for replay and i am also apply linearImpulse and all things and it jumps but can not like mario jump. I want to jump like that.

Comment: I guess it depends on the gravity you set, on the mass of the character and on the magnitude of the force you apply

Comment: I just give you the link of my demo project so you can see what happen in my demo https://docs.google.com/open?id=0By-Zs1EFxoNmRnJFVXJveklGZTQ    And i want to jump like http://www.ikbentomas.nl/other/box2d/